# Angular tutorial Tour of Hero, what does "_" means in the following code

Tags: angular, typescript

I am following the offical tutorial tour of heroes.

I got a question in `hero.service.ts` and the function is to update the new hero using HTTP PUT method.

The code like this:

```
/** PUT: update the hero on the server */
updateHero(hero: Hero): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.put(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions).pipe(
     tap(_ => this.log(`updated hero id=${hero.id}`)),
     catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateHero'))
);
```

So what does `_` mean here in the code?

Comment: It's just naming the single argument to the arrow function `_`, presumably to indicate by convention that they aren't actually going to *use* that argument in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_` is in this case just a blank identifier used to shorten the arrow function. So in this case

```
_ => this.log(`updated hero id=${hero.id}`)
```

would be equivalent to

```
() => this.log(`updated hero id=${hero.id}`)
```

With the minor difference that `_` would be accessible as an argument within the arrow function (although it will likely have the value `undefined`), whereas the second snippet won't have any accessible arguments.

Finally, variables starting with `_` (or just `_` itself) have a special property in typescript. Such variables do not cause a compilation error when they are not used while the `--noUnusedParameters` flag is set.